# Search a specific record from data base using HTML form search bar and PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to search a specific record from the data base using the search bar of html form and php for backend queries. 
Here is my html form code for search:

```
<form style="float: right;margin-right: 80px;margin-top: 30px;" action="search_file.php" method="get">
            <input type="search" name="search">
           </form>
```

Here is my PHP code for searching mechanism or process:

```
<?php


              $search=$_GET['search'];
                $stores = "select * From uploadfile";
                $stores_sql = mysqli_query($conn, $stores);

                while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($stores_sql)){
                    $name = $row1['name'];
                    $city = $row1['city'];
                    $email = $row1['email'];
                    $phone = $row1['phone'];
                    $file = $row1['uploaded_file'];
                    $address=$row1['address'];

                    if($search==$name){
                    echo"<tr><td>$name</td><td>$city</td><td>$phone</td><td>$email</td><td><a href='uploads/$file' download>Download the file</a></td><td>$address</td></tr>";    
                    }
                    elseif($search==$city){
                        echo"<tr><td>$name</td><td>$city</td><td>$phone</td><td>$email</td><td><a href='uploads/$file' download>Download the file</a></td><td>$address</td></tr>";
                    }
                    elseif($search==$email){
                        echo"<tr><td>$name</td><td>$city</td><td>$phone</td><td>$email</td><td><a href='uploads/$file' download>Download the file</a></td><td>$address</td></tr>";
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "keep trying!!!";
                    }



                }
                ?>
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Your code is highly inefficient. You might want to do something like ``select * from uploadfile where ? in (`name`, `city`, `email`)`` (as a prepared query!) so that the database can do the searching for you, rather than dumping the entire table to PHP and looping through it.

Comment: Tell us the problem. My wild guess is that it's not getting the string he wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This Code for searching :

```
$search=$_GET['search'];
$stores = "select * From uploadfile WHERE name = '".$search."' OR city = '".$serach."' OR email ='".$serach."'";
$stores_sql = mysqli_query($conn, $stores);
```

Comment: You need to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering) first and then answer.

Comment: This did the trick thanx very much I really appreciate it... :)

Comment: Please fix the typos for the two variables.

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to

```
"select * From uploadfile where name = '".$search."' or city = '".$search."' or email = '".$search."'";
```

or you can use like queries to fetch all records that similar to search term

```
"select * From uploadfile where name like('%".$search."%)' or city like('%".$search."%)' or email like('%".$search."%)'";
```

Comment: Thanx @rakesh It worked alright!